# Jenkins monitoring plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, github, jenkins

**Here is my eclipse configuration:**

Eclipse Neon,
EGit - Git Team Provider 4.3.1,
M2E Plugin for Maven Integration,
a remote repository on github.com

**What I am able to do:**

Import the remote repository into workspace.
Commit and Push changes to the github.com remote repository
Build using M2E Plugin

**My Question**

I have installed Jenkins on my system. Currently, I may have to install Maven again, install Git again to actually make a build run every time a commit occurs in remote repository on GitHub.com.

Is there a Jenkins plugin for eclipse which, without a local maven/git installation on system, from within the Eclipse IDE, connects to local Jenkins instance and fires a build whenever a commit/push occurs to GitHub.com?

Answer (score 2):

> fires a build whenever a commit/push occurs to GitHub.com?

That is not related to Eclipse.
It is a **[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)** declared [on your GitHub repo](https://github.com/blog/1778-webhooks-level-up), and a listener running locally on your PC and listening for [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent).

In your case, you can add to your local Jenkins server the [GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin). It can:

> Trigger a job when you push to the repository by groking HTTP POSTs from post-receive hook and optionally auto-managing the hook setup.